# joomla k2 - Need to upload pdf file in k2 extra field

Tags: php, joomla

joomla k2 - Need to upload pdf in k2 extra field - any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering create a directory for this in the media manager and store the link to the PDF in the K2 Extra Field.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Attachments tab for it.